# VA-API can't run in a VMware Ubuntu instance

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vmware, gstreamer, vaapi

My system is a Ubuntu 15.10 running in VMware Workstation 12.0.1 on a Windows 10 host and I'm trying to run a program which relies on VAAPI, but when it gets to the initializing VAAPI it returns an error:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.38.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'vmwgfx'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

When I run `vainfo` it displays the same error message.

The problem is that there is no vmgfx_drv_video.so on my system, I tried to link it to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_drv.so` but that didn't help.

I recompiled the VMware video drivers, but that still didn't give me the missing file. (Following these instructions: http://www.mesa3d.org/vmware-guest.html)

My question is: Is there a VMware VA driver out there and if there is then how to get it?

Comment: what kind of graphics driver does it use? according to [this](http://www.slideshare.net/igalia/gstreamervaapi-hardwareaccelerated-encoding-and-decoding-on-intel-hardware) slide 6 - there is limited support based on what driver do you use.. sometimes its tricky to get vaapi with gstreamer working natively, and you are trying on virtual system.. chances are that it wont be possible at all.. but if vainfo give you error.. have you seen  [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247911/how-to-correctly-enable-test-va-api-on-intel-sandy-bridge)?

Comment: It uses the vmwgfx which I got from [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libgl1-mesa-dri) package (this was the default)

Comment: can you change which graphics HW is emulated in vmware(I dont know if thats possible)..

Comment: In the Virtual Machine Settings I can enable/disable 3D Graphics Acceleration, but when it's disabled I can't log in to Ubuntu using the GUI